# Entity Framework Version 6.0 Table-per-Type hierarchy queries retrieve fields from derived types

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I’m building a hiring process with EF Code First version 6.0. I’ve got the following (highly abbreviated) inheritance hierarchy that’s implemented using Table-per-Type:

```
[Table("Person")]
    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[Table("Applicants")]
    public class Applicant : Person
    {
        //Various Applicant properties
        [StringLength(256)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
}

[Table("Employees")]
    public class Employee : Applicant
    {
        public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string WorkPhone { get; set; }
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
//Various other Employee Properties
}
```

Whenever I execute the following query in LINQPad:

```
Applicants.Where(x => x.UserName == "johndoe999")
```

the query returns fields associated with the derived class Employee (HireDate, WorkPhone, JobTitle) which I wasn’t expecting. I’d obviously want it to omit “Employee” related fields when all I’m asking for are applicants.
This doesn’t happen whenever I implemented this same hierarchy as table-per-hierarchy. It should give me the same behavior with Table-per-type, shouldn’t it? Is there something else I need to do to enable this behavior?

I've seen some references to this issue such as ([Entity Framework Table Per Type Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642443/entity-framework-table-per-type-performance)) however this is from '11 in relation to a much older version of EF.

Comment: If you get `Applicants` you necessarily *also* get `Employee`s. Any component that reflects type properties will display the `Employee` properties. I can't imagine that didn't happen with TPH, unless you had the types inherited side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this isn't supported even as of EF 6.1. I found the following work item on codeplex:

https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2332

Here is a link to an article explaining a workaround by mixing Dapper ORM with Entity Framework. According to the author performance increases dramatically.

http://blog.falafel.com/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-tpt-inheritance-mapping-in-entity-framework/

Here is a discussion on EF's github page regarding EF 7 version 1.0 which actually omitted TPT altogether but they state they eventually will put TPT back into EF 7. I just skimmed the article but it isn't clear whether they will address the performance issue with TPT when they add it to EF 7 or if it will work the same as it did in version 6.1.

I will either use Dapper ORM or find a different approach to modeling my data.